# React and Typescript: Can I overload a function with a different number of generics?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript, react-tsx

I am writing a React functional component using typescript.To format the data before submitting it, I want to create a Form component that optionally has a `format` function, and a `FormattedValue` generic type.

However, it shouldn't allow you to use `format`  without setting the generic type, or else you could accidentally submit the form with the wrong type.

I can't figure out how to make a function overload  so that the `Form` function either has the generic `FormattedValue` set and the `format` parameter, or none of them.

This is a minimal example of what I tried to do:

```
import {Form} from "../components/Form"

type FormProps<Value> = {
    submit: (data: Value) => void;
}

type FormattedFormProps<Value, FormattedValue> = {
    submit: (data: FormattedValue) => void;
    format: (value: Value) => FormattedValue
}

function GenericForm<V>({submit}: FormProps<V>): ReactNode;
function GenericForm<V,F>({submit, format}: FormattedFormProps<V, F>) {
  return (
    <Form 
     //...
    onSubmit={(value) => {
        submit(format ? format(value) : value)
    }}
    >
     // ...
    </Form>
  )
}

export default GenericForm
```

This gives the error: `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.(2394)`.

I want to avoid having to create a separate component for a normal form and a form with formatting.

Comment: Your component looks like it's recursive, is that intentional?

Comment: The error "This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature" occurs when the implementation signature of the function is not compatible with all of its overload signatures. To solve the error, make the implementation compatible with all overload signatures

U can read more: [ https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-overload-signature-not-compatible-implementation ] and here is an example for generic form [ https://felixgerschau.com/react-hooks-form-validation-typescript/ ]

Comment: @geoffrey It's not supposed to be recursive, I will edit the example code.

Comment: @Y_T Thanks for the link, I will try to write a form using Hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, it shouldn't allow you to use `format` without setting the generic type, or else you could accidentally submit the form with the wrong type.

I disagree with this because `FormattedFormProps` will ensure that the output of `format` is the input of `submit`. You don't need 2 types, you can simply use that one for both, by making `format` optional

```js
type FormProps<Value, FormattedValue> = {
    submit: (data: FormattedValue) => void;
    format?: (value: Value) => FormattedValue
}

function GenericForm<V, F>({submit, format}: FormProps<V, F>) {
  return (
    <Form 
     //...
    onSubmit={(value) => {
        submit(format ? format(value) : value)
    }}
    >
     // ...
    </Form>
  )
}

// infer FormProps<unknown, number>
const OK1 = GenericForm({submit: (data: number) => {}})

// infer FormProps<string, number>
const OK2 = GenericForm({submit: (data: number) => {}, format: (a: string) => 42})

// infer FormProps<string, number>
const ERROR = GenericForm({submit: (data: number) => {}, format: (a: string) => 'foo'})
//                                                       ~~~~~~
// Type '(a: string) => string' is not assignable to type '(value: string) => number'.
//  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
```

If you want for some reason to restrict the types that must be used for formatting and submitting on the call site you can create variants of `GenericForm` without re-implementing it, like so:

```js
const FormStringToNumber = GenericForm<string, number>;
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. I'll be using this for the form components, combined with an useForm hook.

Comment: "all roads lead to Rome" ;)